# Pass form post data to controller function after jquery validation

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Validation input form wiyj jquery validation
Here is the script  -

```
$('#myform').validate({ 
    rules: {
        amount: {
            required: true,
            //email: true
        }

    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert('valid form submitted'); 

    }
});
```

Here is the codeigniter funtion -

```
  public function test_add(){

  if (!empty($_POST['RentForm'])) {
  echo 4567;
  die;
  }
  }
```

Comment: Please show us your Form. Are you not getting any values in Controller?

Comment: @ascsoftw  Answer q working bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using ajax.

Script

```
var base_url = "<?=base_url();?>";
        $('#myform').validate({ 
            rules: {
                amount: {
                    required: true,
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: base_url+'your_controller/test_add',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('#myform').serialize(),
                    success: (res)=>{
                        // Do Something if success
                        console.log(res);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Your Controller

```
public function test_add(){
            if ($this->input->post('RentForm')) {
                echo $this->input->post('RentForm');
                // Or do Something else
            }
        }
```

Comment: Mark its working.  Thanks, plz tell me how to set success message and page redirection.

Comment: For redirection, you can set
success: (res)=>{            
      window.location.href=base_url+'yourcontroller/redirect_functions';
}

Comment: multiple images upload not working with this script.  can you help Mark

Comment: Please create a new thread with your code and then send your link here